# Apply angular filter on ui-router url params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I want to apply some filter on url params. 
for example:

`ui-sref="stateName({slug:{{someobj.slug | someFilter}}})"`

how can I apply this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need interpolate expressions inside ui-sref. Just enclose the to-be-filtered expression inside round brackets:

```
ui-sref="stateName({slug: (someobj.slug | someFilter)})"
```